# Laravel Date Mutator Requires Parsing?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon. When retrieving attributes that are listed in the $dates property, they will automatically be cast to Carbon instances, allowing you to use any of Carbon's methods on your attributes.

I have the following in dates property - i've not included the created_at and updated_at columns as these are converted by default as per above:

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Then I have the following accessor on the model:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($datetime)
{
    return $datetime->timezone('Europe/London');
}
```

However the above throws the following error:

```
Call to a member function timezone() on string
```

If I change the method to the following it works:

```
 public function getCreatedAtAttribute($datetime)
{
    return Carbon::parse($datetime)->timezone('Europe/London');
}
```

The question is why do I need to parse it since it's suppose cast it to a carbon instance when it's retrieved according to docs https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators ?

Answer (score 1):

That completely depends on what `$datetime` is and how you're passing it this this function. It's clearly a `string`, and not a `Carbon` instance, but you didn't include the definition for `$datetime` in you question, so I can only speculate.

That being said, I haven't see mutators that use an external variable, as they are generally designed to access properties of the class you're applying them to, via `$this`:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute(){
  return $this->created_at->timezone('Europe/London');
}
```

The only caveat I could see with this is naming conflict when trying to use `$model->created_at`. It *should* handle it, but something like `getCreatedAtTzAttribute()`, accesses via `$model->created_at_tz` might be necessary if you come across issues.

Comment: I've omitted the `created_at`, `updated_at` because by default they are converted - see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: You are correct! I didn't think it did that, but yes, by default `Model` (the extension of your model classes) does. Edited answer.

Comment: accessors always have a variable https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor.  I think you are referring to computed accessors which would work as per your example only if I change the name

Comment: Hmm... Clearly I'm out of the loop on this one. I've never used that version of Accessor (that passes/injects a parameter). If it's supposed to pass `$model->created_at` automatically, it would stand to reason that it would be a `Carbon` instance, but isn't. Perhaps this wasn't intended for `Carbon` manipulation this way? The examples in the docs suggest string manipulation (`ucfirst()`), and your error referencing type of `string` also backs that up.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source code ([here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L342)), you'll see that accessors have priority over date casts.

If Eloquent finds an accessor for your date attribute (`getCreatedAtAttribute`), date casting will be ignored. So you'll need to cast it manually within your accessor.

Comment: @adam78, can also borrow `$this->asDateTime($value)` from the source, to cast it semi-manually :)